# UDK: change / set language / localization for game using ini config file

Tags: localization, translation, game-engine, ini, unreal-development-kit

I am translating some UDK Games so there are already some directories like German, English and so on in the Config directory of the UDK Game.

Back in 2010, I had a translation project for an UDK Game and I could set the used language / localization in an INI file (maybe DefaultGame.ini or DefaultEngine.in) but dont know where I did this exactly.

So where do I set the used localization in the right INI file so it will not be overwritten by the files, that are created at the runtime of UDK Games normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set language in DefaultEngine.ini, in section :

```
[Engine.Engine]
Language=JPN
```

so now engine will look for localization files inside "\UDKGame\Localization\JPN" folder